# Traversing the DOM with JavaScript from a specified root Node?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dom

Is there a routine or some function I can use to return to me the element that I request based on the ID, tag name or some other property, **but without** doing global searching using the `document` element?

Here is a sample DOM I am trying to traverse...

I have placed a marker on the element I want to use as the starting point (the btnAction input control) and the element I want to find (the textarea). Look for **[*]**.

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_upAction1">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: left"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="center">
                  <td colspan="1" style=
                  "vertical-align: middle; text-align: center">
[*]                 <input tabindex="0" name=
                    "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvTETstudents$ctl06$btnADDaction"
                    value="ADD" id=
                    "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_btnADDaction"
                    type="submit">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="1" style="text-align: center">
                    <div style=
                    "display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 100001; left: 951.5px; top: 478.5px;"
                    id=
                    "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_upAction2">
                      <div id=
                      "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_pnlACTION"
                      class="pnlACTION">
                        <div id="divHDR">
                          <span id=
                          "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_lblActionHdr">
                          Enter actions for Caine McClelland</span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divBOD">
                          <table style="width: 98%; text-align:left">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                  Please enter action item:<br>
[*]                               <textarea tabindex="0" name=
                                  "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvTETstudents$ctl06$txtAction"
                                  rows="3" cols="20" id=
                                  "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_txtAction"
                                  style="width:98%;">
</textarea> <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_rfvAction"
                                  style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*
                                  Required</span>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                  Select staff assigned to this task:<br>
                                  <select tabindex="0" name=
                                  "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvTETstudents$ctl06$ddlActionStaff"
                                  id=
                                  "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_ddlActionStaff">
                                  <option value="0">
                                      Select...
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="TECNQ204">
                                      Rob Connolly
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="TECNQ143">
                                      Mary Elphick
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="TECNQ210">
                                      Rebecca Edwards
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="TECNQ136">
                                      Wayne Santo
                                    </option>
                                  </select> <span id=
                                  "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_rfvStaff"
                                  style=
                                  "display:inline-block;color:Red;width:98%;visibility:hidden;">
                                  * Required</span>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
                                  <input tabindex="0" name=
                                  "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvTETstudents$ctl06$btnActionOK"
                                  value="OK" id=
                                  "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_btnActionOK"
                                  type="submit"> <input tabindex="0" name=
                                  "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvTETstudents$ctl06$btnActionCANCEL"
                                  value="CANCEL" id=
                                  "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_btnActionCANCEL"
                                  type="submit">
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modalBackground" style=
                    "display: none; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10000; width: 1903px; height: 2986px;"
                    id=
                    "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvTETstudents_ctl06_ajaxMPE_backgroundElement">
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is call a JavaScript function from the btnADDaction `asp:Button` control (like an onclick="findme(this,'txtAction')"), passing `this` as the button element of course, but a related (somewhere in the DOM tree) element via the ID, being in this case "txtAction" from the `asp:TextBox` control.

I've tried of course, `document.getElementByID("txtAction")`, but this starts from the top of the DOM tree. What if I have another txtAction control that is totally unrelated?

Thank you

Comment: Ever heard of jQuery? Sounds like you're going to want to learn it. But really the DOM is all about `document`.

Comment: @PHPglue getting there, but a little boost would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You might not need jquery**. Just created a basic vanilla function to get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} entry
 * @param {string} selector
 * @return {HTMLElement | null}
 */ 
function closest(entry, selector) {
  var parent = entry;
  var element = null;

  while (parent && !element) {
    element = parent.querySelector(selector);
    parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  return element;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
var entry = document.querySelector('input'); // your starting point. 
var textarea = closest(entry, 'textarea'); // <textarea>...</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can use `$('element').closest('some_top_element').find('another_bottom_element')`;

[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) finds the first parent matching the selector (traversing up). And [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) returns the matched childs (traversing down).

If you are not using jquery and want to try using vanilla javascript, check this [tutorial](https://gomakethings.com/climbing-up-and-down-the-dom-tree-with-vanilla-javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript functions you are looking for are [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) and [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName); both can be used based on a parent element instead of `document`. However, the harder part will be finding the ancestor element to base this search on, which is a good use for jQuery's [closest(…)](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

Comment: Yeah the closest() method is what I was after